# How do I tell Devise to use the User model in my scope ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have just begun looking into the Devise gem a little bit and I have a problem with using the correct model for the `User` class. Is there any way I can tell devise to look for the `User` model in my module structure, i.e. can I specify that the `User` model is inside of this module structure:

```
Module1/Module2/User
```

instead of it relying on it being in the default scope ?

Sorry for the short question, if you require anything else, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `class_name` option in the `devise_for` declaration, Devise will use the class you expect. The [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper%3Adevise_for) provides examples.

From the documentation:

```
#  * class_name: setup a different class to be looked up by devise, if it cannot be
#    properly found by the route name.
#
#      devise_for :users, class_name: 'Account'
```